# how to change tableView Cell button on click in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have table view with custom cell and it has button i want that when user click on that button then the image of button should be changes any idea how to do this becuase i want that cellImage button image to be changed in another method.

```
    [cell.theSyncButton addTarget:self action:@selector(syncButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.theSyncButton setTag:indexPath.row];
```

method:

```
-(IBAction)syncButtonAction:(id)sender{
    //   I want to change the cell.SyncButton image here 
}
```

any idea how to do this.

Comment: Is this method called after button pressed `-(IBAction)syncButtonAction:(id)sender`

Comment: yes this is method which is called on button action as shown in code

Comment: after change button image at `syncButtonAction` scroll tableView..is there changed image appear still same after scrolling full table..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of all that code you have all you have to do is:

```
  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
  [cell.theSyncButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: how will cell will call in another method

Comment: This means when the button goes to selective mode it will change to your image.(Goes into selective when user clicks button)

Comment: Yes it should do that

Comment: Then try UIControlStateHighlighted

Comment: Use UIControlStateHighlighted as suggested by Pradhyuman Chavda's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
[btnSync setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnSync setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh-active.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(IBAction)syncButtonAction:(id)sender{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
   [btn setImage:img forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
-(IBAction)syncButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton * syncButton = (UIButton *) sender;
    [syncButton setBackgroundImage: <NormalImage.png>
                          forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [syncButton setBackgroundImage: <HighlightedImage.png
                          forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Comment: is your button is inside TableView cell??

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:
 i use UIImageVIew as button

for example , the starIcon is an UIImageView ,which i add into my custom UITableViewCell as button.
and ArticleCell is my custom UITableViewCell class.

in UITableView dataSource method **cellForRowAtIndexPath**:

```
ArticleCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reused"];
if (cell==nil) {
    NSLog(@"init tableViewCell");
    cell = [[ArticleCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"reused"];
    UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonCallback:)];
    gesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
    [cell.starIcon addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    cell.starIcon.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    NSLog(@"init tableViewCell end");        
}
```

make sure you set **userInteractionEnabled == true;**

then , in your buttonCallback method ,you can get UIimageView by

```
    -(void)buttonCallback:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{
       UIImageView* star = (UIImageView*)[gestureRecognizer view];
    }
```

so , you can change your imageView.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)syncButtonAction:(id)sender{
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```