# How to change tableView Cell button image on click in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Possible duplicates :

[how to change tableView Cell button on click in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013035/how-to-change-tableview-cell-button-on-click-in-iphone)

I have button in table view cell with background images set using this function.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             SectionsTableIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.names[self.keys];
    if (cell.accessoryView == nil) {
        UIImage *buttonUpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_up.png"];
        UIImage *buttonDownImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_down.png"];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setBackgroundImage:buttonUpImage
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:buttonDownImage
                          forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [button setTitle:@"Send" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button sizeToFit];
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(tappedButton:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.accessoryView = button;

    }



    return cell;
}
```

Code for Tapped Button is :

```
- (void)tappedButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSInteger row = sender.tag;
   // NSString *character = self.names[self.keys];
  /*  NSString *key = self.keys[indexPath.row];
    NSArray *nameSection = self.names[key];

    NSString *character = nameSection[indexPath];
   */


   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Request Notification."
                          message:[NSString
                                   stringWithFormat:@"Friend Request Sent ."]
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

  /*  UIImage *buttonUpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [cell.theSyncButton setImage:buttonUpImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonUpImage
                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button setTitle:@"Sent" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [button sizeToFit];
   */
}
```

Now i require is to change background color and title to "sent" dynamically when user click on "Send" button in table view cell .How i can get this functionality ?

Comment: Change button background image in `tappedButton:` using `[sender setBackgroundImage:buttonUpImage
                      forState:UIControlStateNormal]`

Comment: [sender  setImage:buttonUpImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];   still not working

Comment: After setting image try reloading the cell by `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ....
    UIButton *button;
    if (cell.accessoryView == nil) {
        ...
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        ....
        cell.accessoryView = button;
    }
    button.tag = indexPath.row;

    ...
}
```

in `tappedButton:`

```
- (void)tappedButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
     NSInteger row = sender.tag;
    UIImage *buttonUpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
    [sender setBackgroundImage:buttonUpImage
                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [sender setTitle:@"Sent" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

Comment: Error on last 3 lines "Property table view not found on object of type Controller " :    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

Comment: `self.tableView` refers to the tableView. (Hope the tableView have an `IBOutlet` connected), if yes replace that name with `self.tableView`

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can do following,

```
- (void)tappedButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [sender setTitle:@"Sent" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Request Notification."
                      message:[NSString
                               stringWithFormat:@"Friend Request Sent ."]
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show]; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your IBAction method tappedButton you get passed the button that the user tapped (the "sender" parameter.)

Change the background color and title of "sender"

Answer (score 1):

Use selected state of button, in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [button setTitle:@"Send" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:original_image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:@"Sent" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setBackgroundImage:selected_image forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

In `tappedButton()` function set sender to selected using `[sender setSelected:YES]`

The main reason for this approch is you can detect state of button using `isSelected` method.

Comment: Images is changing correctly ..But title is not appearing ..in both before and after the click event ..

Comment: @user3482051 use title & image code in Cell initialization section & in your action function set it active using [sender setSelected:YES]

Comment: sorry i am not clear about which action function you are pointing to ...please make it clear in above code ...

Comment: button doesnt appear by using this:     [button setBackgroundImage:buttonUpImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];  button without title appear by using this :      [button setBackgroundImage:buttonUpImage
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];   How i can make title visible ??

Comment: you have to use specify title & image for both Normal & Selected state. I've updated my code again, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
((UIButton *)sender).titleLabel.text = @"title";
```